# C++ executeQuery() error displaying MySQL data from table

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I need some help. I had this code (below), to add data to a MySQL table and then return that same table. The code is doing fine, when I run it it adds the column to the MySQL table BUT it stops, with the error:

```
SQL error. Error message:
```

Literally blank. If I use a `SELECT` statement rather than an `INCLUDE` one in `executeQuery()`, it runs with no problem and no error message, just displays my table (or parts of it). What am I missing?

I am using Visual Studios 2015, and MySQL Server.

The end-goal is to connect an API with an SQL table using C++, to record data according to a specific timespan. This is one of the first steps, just to make sure that I can link MySQL with C++ properly.

Sorry if this post is poorly written, first time here and definitely not an experienced programmer... Also, I looked into other threads, but as this is so specific I could not find them helpful.

```
// Standard C++ includes
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Include the Connector/C++ headers
#include "cppconn/driver.h"
#include "cppconn/exception.h"
#include "cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "cppconn/statement.h"

// Link to the Connector/C++ library
#pragma comment(lib, "mysqlcppconn.lib")

// Specify our connection target and credentials
const string server = "127.0.0.1:3306";
const string username = "root";
const string password = "root";
const string database = "dbex"; 
const string table = "tbex";

int main()
{
    sql::Driver     *driver; // Create a pointer to a MySQL driver object
    sql::Connection *dbConn; // Create a pointer to a database connection object
    sql::Statement  *stmt;   // Create a pointer to a Statement object to hold our SQL commands
    sql::ResultSet  *res;    // Create a pointer to a ResultSet object to hold the results of any queries we run

                             // Try to get a driver to use to connect to our DBMS
    try
    {
        driver = get_driver_instance();
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "Could not get a database driver. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Try to connect to the DBMS server
    try
    {
        dbConn = driver->connect(server, username, password);
        dbConn->setSchema(database);
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "Could not connect to database. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    stmt = dbConn->createStatement();

    // Try to query the database
    try
    {
        //stmt->execute("USE " + database);              // Select which database to use. Notice that we use "execute" to perform a command.
        res = stmt->executeQuery("INSERT INTO "+ table +"(Brand, Model, Power, `Last Used`,`# Times Used`) VALUES('Ferrari','Modena','500','Never',0)"); 
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cars"); // Perform a query and get the results. Notice that we use "executeQuery" to get results back

    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "SQL error. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

// While there are still results (i.e. rows/records) in our result set...
    while (res->next())
    {
        cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
    }

    delete res;
    delete stmt;
    delete dbConn;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

in line:

```
res = stmt->executeQuery("INSERT INTO "+ table +"(Brand, Model, Power, `Last Used`,`# Times Used`) VALUES('Ferrari','Modena','500','Never',0)");
```

You are making a wrong string concatenation, that + (plus) operator don't work that way, that code don't concatenate strings, instead is adding pointers.

Just simply replace this way and try again:

```
#define TABLE "tbex"// put this in top of cpp file
......
res = stmt->executeQuery("INSERT INTO " TABLE "(Brand, Model, Power, `Last Used`
,`# Times Used`) VALUES('Ferrari','Modena','500','Never',0)");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this and had the same problem as before: the row is added to the table, but it still displays a blank error message and stops code after adding

Answer (score 0):

An INSERT is not a query. Try using executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery().

Replace this line

```
res = stmt->executeQuery("INSERT INTO "+ table +"(Brand, Model, Power, `Last Used`,`# Times Used`) VALUES('Ferrari','Modena','500','Never',0)");
```

with the following lines (you may need an additional .h file):

```
sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;

pstmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+ table +"(Brand, Model, Power, `Last Used`,`# Times Used`) VALUES('Ferrari','Modena','500','Never',0)");
res = pstmt->executeUpdate();
delete pstmt;
```

Look at the official MySQL example [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-2.html) for an example of the concept.

You may also try using execute(), as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480741/which-execute-function-should-i-use-in-mysql-connector-c) Stackoverflow question. The function execute() is used for generic SQL commands, but may not be as verbose in its return value as more specified functions (it returns a boolean).