# Error message after inserting to a table in MYSQL db

Tags: c++, mysql

I have this c++ code that works fine, i can read from the tables and write to the tables:

```
int main()

{


    // Try to get a driver to use to connect to our DBMS
    try
    {
        driver = get_driver_instance();
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "Could not get a database driver. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Try to connect to the DBMS server
    try
    {
        dbConn = driver->connect(server, username, password);
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "Could not connect to database. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    stmt = dbConn->createStatement(); // Specify which connection our SQL statement should be executed on

    // Try to query the database
    try
    {
        stmt->execute("USE test");  // Select which database to use. Notice that we use "execute" to perform a command.

        res = stmt->executeQuery("INSERT INTO users (fName, lName, age) VALUES ('fname', 'lname', 25)"); // Perform a query and get the results. Notice that we use "executeQuery" to get results back
        //res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
        //return 0;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "SQL error. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }


    sql::ResultSetMetaData *res_meta = res -> getMetaData();
    int columns = res_meta -> getColumnCount();


    // While there are still results (i.e. rows/records) in our result set...
    while (res->next())
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                cout << res->getString(i) << " | " ;
                }
         cout << endl;
    }

    delete res;
    delete stmt;
    delete dbConn;
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So, this inserts to the table but then i get this error message

> SQL error. Error message:  sh: 1: pause: not found

This doesn't happen if i use the "select".

Also i know that this question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186131/c-executequery-error-displaying-mysql-data-from-table) but unfortunately it has no answer so i'm asking again.

Comment: Are you on a Windows computer or not? `system("pause")` will not work outside Windows.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah no i'm using linux

Comment: well i don't think its the problem, because even if i comment out the whole catch statement. The still exits

Comment: Can you print error code: `cout << "MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();`?

Comment: @ks1322 This is the result **SQL error. Error message: 0**

Comment: Looks related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/6903383/72178. Try `stmt->execute("INSERT INTO users (fName, lName, age) VALUES ('fname', 'lname', 25)");`.

Comment: @ks1322 execute() returned this error: `error: cannot convert ‘bool’ to ‘sql::ResultSet*’ in assignment ute("INSERT INTO users (fName, lName, age) VALUES ('fName', 'lName', 25)"); // Perform a query and get the results. Notice that we use "executeQuery" to get results back`

Comment: @Arnav: `echo 'alias pause=read' >> ~/.bashrc` Now it does :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question looks related to [MySQL Query executes but throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6903383/72178).

`executeQuery()` assumes that sql query should return `sql::ResultSet` but your `INSERT INTO` query does not. You can use `execute()` instead, which returns true or false:

```
try
{
    stmt->execute("USE test");
    stmt->execute("INSERT INTO users (fName, lName, age) VALUES ('fname', 'lname', 25)");
}
catch (sql::SQLException e)
{
    cout << "SQL error. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An INSERT is not a query. Try using executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery(). Look at the official MySQL example [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-2.html).

Replace this line

```
res = stmt->executeQuery("INSERT INTO users (fName, lName, age) VALUES ('fname', 'lname', 25)"); // Perform a query and get the results. Notice that we use "executeQuery" to get results back
```

with the following lines (you may need a new .h file):

```
sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;

pstmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (fName, lName, age) 
VALUES ('fname', 'lname', 25)");
res = pstmt->executeUpdate();
delete pstmt;
```

You may also try using execute(), as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480741/which-execute-function-should-i-use-in-mysql-connector-c) Stackoverflow question. The function execute() is used for generic SQL commands, but may not be as verbose in its return value as more specified functions (it returns a boolean).

Comment: executeUpdate() returned this error:
`error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘sql::ResultSet*’ [-fpermissive]
   res = stmt->executeUpdate("INSERT INTO users (fName, lName, age) VALUES ('fName', 'lName', 25)"); // Perform a query and get the results. Notice that we use "executeQuery" to get results back`

while execute() returned this error:
`error: cannot convert ‘bool’ to ‘sql::ResultSet*’ in assignment
 ute("INSERT INTO users (fName, lName, age) VALUES ('fName', 'lName', 25)"); // Perform a query and get the results. Notice that we use "executeQuery" to get results back`

Comment: I just edited my answer to have a code example. It might get around that error.